# How to use a function onto np.roll() like DataFrame.rolling().apply(function) or dataframe.rolling().agg(function)?

Tags: python, numpy, rolling-computation

I have the below function and would like to apply it onto a numpy.roll. I have searched the internet to no avail, and most np.roll solutions on stackoverflow tend to show how to do the rolling function but that's not what I am looking for.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], "B": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
df_a = np.array(df)

def first_variance(X):
    pca = PCA(n_components=1)
    pca.fit(X)
    return pca.explained_variance_

np.roll(df_a, 10)
```

Is there a way to employ a function on this rolling numpy function like you would on a pandas df?

**EDIT**

The expected outcome for this would be a timeseries dataframe for the outcome. Please ignore the fact the numbers are the same. In actuality this will not be the case, had to whip something up to use as a demonstration.

```
         PCA 1 Expl Var PCA 2 Expl Var  PCA 3 Expl Var  PCA 4 Expl Var  PCA 5 Expl Var
2021-10-01  0.011044    0.004083    0.003389    0.002877    0.002368
2021-10-11  0.011044    0.004083    0.003389    0.002877    0.002368
2021-10-21  0.011044    0.004083    0.003389    0.002877    0.002368
2021-10-31  0.011044    0.004083    0.003389    0.002877    0.002368
2021-11-11  0.011044    0.004083    0.003389    0.002877    0.002368
2021-11-21  0.011044    0.004083    0.003389    0.002877    0.002368
2021-12-01  0.011044    0.004083    0.003389    0.002877    0.002368
2021-12-11  0.011044    0.004083    0.003389    0.002877    0.002368
2021-12-21  0.011044    0.004083    0.003389    0.002877    0.002368
2021-12-31  0.011044    0.004083    0.003389    0.002877    0.002368
```

I was going to turn the array into a df. When I tried the df.rolling(3).apply(first_variance), I got this error:

`ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[1. 2. 3.]. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.`

So I decided to turn it into an array and then run the rolling function on it and then turn the array into a df to look like the above.

Comment: What do you expect `np.roll` to do? It's nothing like `df.rolling`.

Comment: I know its not like df.rolling, I wanted to know if I could apply the function to the array for every 10 values like a dataframe would for every ten rows using df.rolling(10).apply(function). But I want to apply np.roll() to the first_variance(X) function in the above code.

Comment: np.roll` returns a new array.  It does not act in-place.

Comment: What is the expected output for your example?

Comment: @Michael Szczesny, I have updated the code to showcase the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The (almost) numpy equivalent of `pd.rolling` is `sliding_window_view`

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

WINDOWSIZE = 3

# Pandas version
pd_out = df.rolling(WINDOWSIZE).sum()

# Numpy version
np_out = sliding_window_view(df_a, (WINDOWSIZE, df_a.shape[1])).sum(axis=2).squeeze()
```

Output:

```
>>> pd_out
      A     B
0   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   NaN
2   6.0   9.0
3   9.0  12.0
4  12.0  15.0
5  15.0  18.0
6  18.0  21.0
7  21.0  24.0

>>> np_out
array([[ 6,  9],
       [ 9, 12],
       [12, 15],
       [15, 18],
       [18, 21],
       [21, 24]])
```

**N.B.**: note the missing nan for the numpy version so the number of lines is not the same from your original array.

Detail of `sliding_window_view`:

```
>>> sliding_window_view(df_a, (WINDOWSIZE, df_a.shape[1]))
array([[[[1, 2],
         [2, 3],
         [3, 4]]],


       [[[2, 3],
         [3, 4],
         [4, 5]]],


       [[[3, 4],
         [4, 5],
         [5, 6]]],


       [[[4, 5],
         [5, 6],
         [6, 7]]],


       [[[5, 6],
         [6, 7],
         [7, 8]]],


       [[[6, 7],
         [7, 8],
         [8, 9]]]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would I apply the function `first_variance` in my original code to the rolling window instead of `sum(axis=2)`?

Comment: Take a look to `apply_along_axis` and `apply_over_axes`

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help. Though it did not work but I will try and find another way of doing this. Regardless, thanks for your help